# What is the different between P2P server and Node?

Tags: go-ethereum, devp2p

I checked go-ethereum code and I see 2 files:

`/go-ethereum/p2p/server.go`:

```
type Server struct {
    // Config fields may not be modified while the server is running.
    Config

    // Hooks for testing. These are useful because we can inhibit
    // the whole protocol stack.
    newTransport func(net.Conn) transport
    newPeerHook  func(*Peer)

    lock    sync.Mutex // protects running
    running bool

    nodedb       *enode.DB
    localnode    *enode.LocalNode
    ntab         discoverTable
    listener     net.Listener
    ourHandshake *protoHandshake
    lastLookup   time.Time
    DiscV5       *discv5.Network

    // These are for Peers, PeerCount (and nothing else).
    peerOp     chan peerOpFunc
    peerOpDone chan struct{}

    quit          chan struct{}
    addstatic     chan *enode.Node
    removestatic  chan *enode.Node
    addtrusted    chan *enode.Node
    removetrusted chan *enode.Node
    posthandshake chan *conn
    addpeer       chan *conn
    delpeer       chan peerDrop
    loopWG        sync.WaitGroup // loop, listenLoop
    peerFeed      event.Feed
    log           log.Logger
}
```

AND

`/go-ethereum/node/node.go`

```
type Node struct {
    eventmux *event.TypeMux // Event multiplexer used between the services of a stack
    config   *Config
    accman   *accounts.Manager

    ephemeralKeystore string         // if non-empty, the key directory that will be removed by Stop
    instanceDirLock   flock.Releaser // prevents concurrent use of instance directory

    serverConfig p2p.Config
    server       *p2p.Server // Currently running P2P networking layer

    serviceFuncs []ServiceConstructor     // Service constructors (in dependency order)
    services     map[reflect.Type]Service // Currently running services

    rpcAPIs       []rpc.API   // List of APIs currently provided by the node
    inprocHandler *rpc.Server // In-process RPC request handler to process the API requests

    ipcEndpoint string       // IPC endpoint to listen at (empty = IPC disabled)
    ipcListener net.Listener // IPC RPC listener socket to serve API requests
    ipcHandler  *rpc.Server  // IPC RPC request handler to process the API requests

    httpEndpoint  string       // HTTP endpoint (interface + port) to listen at (empty = HTTP disabled)
    httpWhitelist []string     // HTTP RPC modules to allow through this endpoint
    httpListener  net.Listener // HTTP RPC listener socket to server API requests
    httpHandler   *rpc.Server  // HTTP RPC request handler to process the API requests

    wsEndpoint string       // Websocket endpoint (interface + port) to listen at (empty = websocket disabled)
    wsListener net.Listener // Websocket RPC listener socket to server API requests
    wsHandler  *rpc.Server  // Websocket RPC request handler to process the API requests

    stop chan struct{} // Channel to wait for termination notifications
    lock sync.RWMutex

    log log.Logger
}
```

What are the differences in purpose between these two?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Server.go(p2p.Server) is responsible for synchronize data from others p2p node(running P2P networking layer).
The Node.go is responsible for all thing of an Ethereum node, ie: sync data, RPC server, etc.

As you see, Node.go has a property is p2p.Server.

Comment: Thank you, Van C. I have a question: "The Server.go(p2p.Server) is responsible for synchronize data from others p2p node. The Node.go is responsible for ... sync data..." What is the different between these 2 sentences?

Comment: I mean, p2p.Server only runs p2p network layer. While, the Node.go uses p2p.Server as its property, but the Node.go also run other services like: RPC http server, WS server and so on.